# Are Vegeta and Goku of the same age, or do they have several years of difference?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-movies

The second trailer of the movie *Dragon Ball Super: Broly* seems to show Goku and Vegeta were born at the same time.

Is this so, didn't the series state differently? If so, which version of *Dragon Ball* story would be canon now, the series or this movie?

Comment: Vegeta is older than goku, you can see in series it is stated that when freeza destorys planet Vegeta, vegeta was with Nappa somewhere else, where Goku was just born

Answer (score 2):

There is no doubt that Vegeta is older as Goku was only an infant (about 0-1 yr old) when he was sent to Earth, while Vegeta was already fighting in another planet (about 5 yrs old), so Vegeta is about 5 yrs older than Goku.

Note however, that both Goku and Vegeta have died several times (both twice I think) and both have trained in the "Spirit and Time Room"* where staying 1 day is equal to 1 year in the outside/real world. So their physical bodies are several years younger than their actual ages.

*I don't know how they translate this in the English dub/sub, but this is how I would based on the original Japanese 精神と時の部屋.

Sources (Japanese):

1. https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2141825142662556801
2. https://unotarou.com/anime/33645/

Comment: Did you mean to say that their physical bodies are several years older than their actual ages, rather than younger? In the Room of Spirit and Time, their bodies age a year while their chronological age increases only a day.

Comment: I think you are right about Vegeta as he was only dead for a short time each of the two times that he died, but stayed for 2 yrs (2 days) in the Room of Spirit and Time. But Goku was dead for 1 yr (by Piccolo), then another 7 yrs after Cell so that's -8 yrs to his physical body's age. If we add 2, it's still -6 yrs.

Answer (score 1):

It does not necessarily show that both Goku and Vegeta were born in the same year in the new movie. It is mever shown that Goku and Vegeta are both in saiyan incnbators at the same time so they are not the same age. Even if they are in incubators at the same time one may be in for a longer period in comparison to the other. When Goku was in an incubator it was shown that Vegeta was on another planet with Nappa as their home planet got destroyed. While Vegeta was on anothet planet it was shown that Goku was still in an incubator and then Bardock decied to put him in a pod and send him to Earth where he may lived safely.

Also, Vegeta was said to be born in the Year 732 while Goku in 737 so Vegeta is 5 years older than Goku.

However, the time both have spent in the Hyperbolic time chamber make them a year older than they actually should have been and if you want to classify it as this then you can. Their physical bodies are older than their actual ages.